# calculation of the exponent of a matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

Could you, please, help me to understand what I am doing wrong:
I am calculating exp(A), where A=[-1 0;0 -1]
By my calculation with series, I got [1/e -1,0;0, 1/e-1].
Matlab and Wolfram give me [1/e,1;1;1/e].
Rules in Perko "differential Equations..." give me [1/e, 0;0, 1/e].

please, kindly explain why I got three different answers.
Thank you.
Verba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $d_1,\dots,d_n$, then $e^D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $e^{d_1},\dots,e^{d_n}$. This follows from the power series definition of $e^D$.

What exactly did you enter into Wolfram? When I tried it in Mathematica I got the right answer.

Comment: I entered exp({{-1,0},{0,-1}}).

Comment: It probably treated this as a list, not a matrix. Try MatrixExp instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked.